# MariaDB master->slave replication problem

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication

I have replication (master->slave) between 2 MariaDB servers. (almost) Everything is working properly but once for a few weeks replication stops working. There is no mysqld process on slave machine.

In /var/lib/mysql/ directory there are few thousands files like mysqld-relay-bin.026342.

Below are logs from slave server.

```
Sep  6 14:15:52 maria02 mysqld[7303]: 2021-09-06 14:15:52 11 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Relay log read failure: Could not parse relay log event entry. The possible reasons are: the master's binary log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the binary log), the slave's relay log is corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the relay log), a network problem, or a bug in the master's or slave's MySQL code. If you want to check the master's binary log or slave's relay log, you will be able to know their names by issuing 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' on this slave. Internal MariaDB error code: 1594
Sep  6 14:15:52 maria02 mysqld[7303]: 2021-09-06 14:15:52 11 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mariadb-bin.000054' position 466175364
Sep  6 14:15:52 maria02 mysqld[7303]: 2021-09-06 14:15:52 11 [Note] Slave SQL thread exiting, replication stopped in log 'mariadb-bin.000054' at position 466175364
Sep  6 14:15:52 maria02 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.18 database server.
```

Comment: when you follow the instructions `you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog'` what does it arrive at? What is the size of `mariadb-bin.000054`? What version is the master?

Comment: Master version: Server version: 10.3.18-MariaDB-1:10.3.18
All files like mariadb-bin.xxxxx have 344 bytes.